# The Closure of Convex Hull of an orthonormal basis in a separable Hilbert space has empty interior

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Given $H$ a separable Hilbert space and $\left\{e_n\right\}$ an orthonormal basis, then $int(\overline{Conv(\left\{e_n\right\})}) = \emptyset.$

I don't know where to start, one thing I know is $\overline{span(\left\{e_n\right\})} = H$, will Baire's Category Theorem be used in the proof? Could anyone give some hints?

I come up with a solution today but I do not know if it is correct:

**Sol.**
(**I have edited the proof again!**)

First, set $A_n := conv({e_1,e_2,...,e_n})$, it is not difficult to show that $A_n$ is closed. I claim that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $int(A_n) = \emptyset$. Otherwise, suppose $\exists N$ such that $int(A_N) \neq \emptyset$, then it contains some open ball, say
$$
B(x_0;\delta) \subset A_N,
$$
$\exists a_1, a_2,...,a_n \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$ such that $x_0 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$, by choosing $\epsilon < \delta / \sqrt{2}$, I can show
$$
y := a_1 e_1 + a_2e_2 + ...+a_{N-1}e_{N-1} + (a_N - \epsilon)e_N + \epsilon e_{N+1} \notin A_N,
$$
but
$$
\|y - x_0\| < \delta,
$$
this gives a contradiction.

Finally, we have (It is not easy to show, but true)
$$
\overline{conv(\left\{e_n\right\})} = \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_n},
$$
Note that a countable union of meager sets is still meager, thus, $int(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_n) = \emptyset$, also, $int(cl(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_n)) = int(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_n) = \emptyset$(some topological facts of convex sets are used...) $\square$

Comment: First, try to see that no open ball (of positive radius) centered at $0$ is contained in that set...

Comment: E.g., compute the norm of ${1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n e_j$

Answer (score 2):

The map $S:\ell^1\to H$, $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\mapsto \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n e_n$ is well defined (because $\ell^1\subseteq \ell^2$) linear, continuous and injective. If $\overline{Conv\{e_n:n\in\mathbb N\}}$ contained interior ponits, $S$ would be *almost open*, i.e., $\overline{S(B_{\ell^1})}$ would be a $0$-neighbourhood. The open mapping theorem (e.g., the version in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*) would imply that $S$ is an isomorphism which isn't true, e.g., since Hilbert spaces are reflexive and $\ell^1$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be your closed convex hull. An arbitrary $c \in C$ can be written as
$$
c = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \alpha_n e_n
$$
and we always have $\alpha_n \ge 0$. Moreover, $\alpha_n \to 0$.
In particular,
$$
c - 2 \alpha_m e_m \not\in C$$
for all $m \ge 1$.
Thus, $c$ cannot be an interior point.

Answer (score 1):

Show that if $x\in \overline{\operatorname{conv}\{e_n\}}$ then $x+ie_1\not\in \overline{\operatorname{conv}\{e_n\}}$.

Then consider the sequence $x+\frac in\,e_1$.

Comment: The result is true for real Hilbert spaces also. Your proof assumes that the scalar field is $\mathbb C$.